# Applying a git patch from a previous commit to a later commit

Tags: git, patch

Let's say the git tree appears as:

```
1 ----> 2 ----> 3 -----> 4(HEAD/MASTER)
      \
       \ (PATCH)
        --2A->
```

and I have a patch that is a diff of 2 and 2A which adds a feature.

Is there a smart way of applying this patch to the latest commit?
Assuming that all I have is the patch file and the git repo of the main line.

Comment: Did you try `git am <file.patch>` or `git apply <file.patch>`?...

Answer (score 1):

Try the simple way first. If you are already on master,

```
git apply PATCH
```

If the patch does not apply to HEAD / master, try this:

```
git checkout 2
git apply PATCH
git tag patch-applied
git checkout master
git cherry-pick patch-applied
```

OR

```
git checkout 2
git apply PATCH
git tag patch-applied
git checkout master
git merge patch-applied
```

For both the merge and the rebase it can happen that you need to resolve conflicts.
rebase gives you a linear history, merge gives you a branched history.

You can use [git lola](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) to have a look at the history you created.

Comment: edited my answer, if you do it like this you need cherry-pick instead of rebase.

Answer (score 0):

As [TheCodeArtist points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331599/applying-a-git-patch-from-a-previous-commit-to-a-later-commit#comment26907007_18331599), if you have a patch file, you can apply it by simply using `git apply <patch>`:

```
git checkout master
git apply <patch>
```

According to the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git apply`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html):

> ## NAME
>
> > git-apply - Apply a patch to files and/or to the index
>
> ## DESCRIPTION
>
> > Reads the supplied diff output (i.e. "a patch") and applies it to files.
> >
> > This command applies the patch but does not create a commit. Use [git-am(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) to create commits from patches generated by [git-format-patch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) and/or received by email.